# Como integrar uma Aplicação Web com um banco de dados PostGIS? Qual o melhor caminho?

Tags: postgresql, microsoft-azure, postgis

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web utilizando a plataforma Azure. Optei por usar o banco de Dados PostgreSQL com extensão PostGIS, pois a aplicação se resume em um WebGis e o PostGis é o que melhor me atende. Estou usando o recurso WebApp do Azure, onde no mesmo tenho o PHP como linguagem. Gostaria de saber qual o melhor caminho para que eu consiga utilizar a aplicação e integrar ela a esse banco de dados.

Ps: Eu criei uma Maquina Virtual Ubuntu 14.04 e instalei o PostgreSQL nela, porém não sei como fazer essa integração, e os testes que tentei não deram certo. Esse é o melhor modo? Se sim como faço essa conexão entre os dois recursos.

Obrigado!

Comment: Nós só podemos ajudar se você mostrar código. A sua pergunta está muito ampla.

Comment: O Melhor caminho para mim pode ser o pior caminho para você.

Comment: O problema não era o código em si, e sim a infraestrutura escolhida. Não estava conseguindo conectar e liberar acesso da minha maquina virtual.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema. 
Estava criando o WebApp e a VM em redes e grupos de recursos diferentes. Criei então uma nova maquina virtual (Windows Server 8) e um novo grupo de recurso, colocando a aplicação no mesmo lugar. Configurei o Postgresql, os aquivos (pg_hba.conf e postgresql.conf), os prontos de extremidades liberando acesso a porta e também liberando o firewall para a porta 5432. 
Feito isso consegui fazer a aplicação conversar com o banco através da função pg_connect(), conectada ao DNS ou IP do serviço de nuvem da maquina, na porta do banco (5432);

Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Parabéns. Continue assim.

Answer (score 0):

Para tornar sua vida mais fácil, existe no Azure Marktplace uma VM já com tudo isso configurado: [OpenGeo Suite](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/marketplace/partners/boundlessgeo/opengeosuite/).

- Manage and store data reliably with PostGIS
- Publish maps and data from a variety of formats and sources with GeoServer
- Build flexible user interfaces and custom workflows in the browser with
- OpenLayers
- Analyze and publish geospatial data on the desktop with QGIS
- Access and edit data using open standards from top to bottom,
  including OGC standards like WMS, WFS, WCS, and others.

Para mais inforações, acesse o [site oficial](http://www.boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-su%C3%ADte);

Comment: Vi essa VM lá. Não tinha optado por ela por causa dessas outras ferramentas integradas que não se encaixa no meu projeto e com as plataformas que estou usando. Mas consegui resolver o problema. Muito Obrigado!